# Incorrect syntax near '-'

Tags: asp.net

can someone help me with this code ?!
i have some problems when submit the infos,
can not add to the database.This is created for log-in form i add all the infos and stuff but its not working can someone take a look at this code maybe find a bug.

`$`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(IsPostBack)
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegisterConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        string checkuser = "select count(*) from UserDataT where Username='" +TextBoxUN.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        if (temp == 1)
        {

            Response.Write("Ky user egziston");

        }


        conn.Close();
    }
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegisterConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        conn.Open();

        string insertQuery = "insert into UserDataT (Username,E-Mail,Password,Shteti) values (@Uname ,@email ,@password ,@shteti)";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uname", TextBoxUN.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBoxEM.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBoxPW.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shteti", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString());

        com.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Response.Redirect("Manager.aspx");
        Response.Write("Regjistrimi eshte bere me sukses");



        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("ERROR:" + ex.ToString());
    }
```

`$`

Comment: Please include the exact line that is causing the error.  You should do this in the future with all questions asked here.

Comment: Pretty sure this is related to your column "E-Mail".

Answer (score 1):

`E-Mail` is not a valid [identifier](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx) in SQL. Generally speaking it's best to avoid creating column names like this, however, if you're stuck with this column name, try delimiting the identifier like this:

```
string insertQuery = "insert into UserDataT (Username,[E-Mail],Password,Shteti) values (@Uname ,@email ,@password ,@shteti)";
```

But personally, I prefer to delimit *all* table or column names in SQL queries just as a matter of style, because it helps to more clearly identify the various parts of the query, like this:

```
string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO [UserDataT] ([Username],[E-Mail],[Password],[Shteti]) VALUES (@Uname ,@email ,@password ,@shteti)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
string insertQuery = "insert into UserDataT (Username,E-Mail,Password,Shteti) values (@Uname ,@email ,@password ,@shteti)";
```

to this:

```
string insertQuery = "insert into UserDataT (Username,[E-Mail],Password,Shteti) values (@Uname ,@email ,@password ,@shteti)";
```

Notice that I changed `E-Mail` to `[E-Mail]`.  If you have a column or table name with spaces or dashes you need to include the square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

In the insert statement

```
insert into UserDataT (Username,E-Mail,Password,Shteti)
```

You cannot write E-Mail, because the minus sign is not a valid character unless the column name is surrounded by [].  If the column is really called that, write it as [E-Mail].  Otherwise, use the correct column name.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with your column named "E-Mail". Either rename the column (preferred) to something without a hyphen (Email) or wrap the column name inside brackets [E-Mail]

I recommend renaming the table column